# How to resolve "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext" for registry "addViewControllers" tests?

Tags: java, spring, junit5

I am writing a barebones junit5 test to test a view, but no matter how I set up the file, I get the same error over and over.  As a noob, I was wondering if anyone could guide me to the answer/or just tell me what combination of things I am doing is wrong.

Test File

```
package com.example;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.context.support.StaticApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;

// @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class MyViewTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    // private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    private ViewControllerRegistry registry;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        this.registry = new ViewControllerRegistry(new StaticApplicationContext());
        // this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testAddViewControllers() throws Exception {
        MyViewview = new MyView();
        view.addViewControllers(registry);

        mockMvc.perform(get("/"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(view().name("forward:/public/index"));
    }
}
```

Here are the parts of my POM that I think are relevant

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

And the View

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class MyView implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers( ViewControllerRegistry registry ) {
        registry.addViewController( "/" ).setViewName( "forward:/public/index" );
        registry.setOrder( Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE );
    }
}
```

I've tried all combinations of online examples for the class @, using just @SpringBootTest, just the @AutoConfigureMockMvc, the @ExtendWith, and all possible permutations, as well as @autowiring the mvc, and trying to build it in the setup.

EDIT
The stack trace meant nothing to me, but it was wrong of me to assume.
Stack Trace, last caused by

````
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given type must be an interface!
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:121) ~[spring-core-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.AbstractRepositoryMetadata.<init>(AbstractRepositoryMetadata.java:60) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.AnnotationRepositoryMetadata.<init>(AnnotationRepositoryMetadata.java:45) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.AbstractRepositoryMetadata.getMetadata(AbstractRepositoryMetadata.java:78) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.getRepositoryConfigurations(RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.java:103) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.registerRepositoriesIn(RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.java:149) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.registerBeanDefinitions(AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.java:62) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.lambda$loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars$1(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:396) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:395) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:157) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:129) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:343) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:782) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:774) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:123) ~[spring-boot-test-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124) ~[spring-test-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        ... 67 common frames omitted
    ```
````

Comment: I continue to be amazed how few people know how to [read stack traces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors). The root cause of the error is the last "Caused by" in the stack trace, not the first line you provided us with ...

Comment: Thank you for clarifying @meriton that I indeed did miss the obvious caused by, I updated with my stack trace.  My bad for forgetting to include it

Comment: Well, that [complains](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/main/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/repository/core/support/AbstractRepositoryMetadata.java#L59) that your repository interface is not, in fact, an interface. Try setting a breakpoint in the line of code throwing this exception to find out which repository interface Spring is complaining about ...

Comment: @meriton, i guess i have some diving to do to see why this is occurring.  Any ideas why Spring is trying to instantiate my repos at all?  Why isnt the test just staying scoped to the single test?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @mertion for the string handed guide in the right direction.

Just because my test was not testing any repositories, doesn't mean the test didn't try to instantiate them.
I had a test call 'MyRepo' instead of 'MyRepoTest', so Spring was instantiating the test as the real repo, which was causing my issue.

So renaming a file fixed my issue.